# What would you do when accidentally push your feature branch to a remote repository?

Tags: git

If you accidentally push your feature branch to a remote repository, and now  regret about it, what can you do?

Comment: - a brief about, why would you regret would help understand the questions clearly.
- I assume, you have pushed a local feature branch to remote. You are using Git, there is no point regretting if this is the case. Unless you have merged it with the master or release branch.

Comment: Probably the best approach would be no longer regret - https://github.com/hendrixroa/in-case-of-fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the history of that feature branch, and force push it, effectively rewriting the sequence of commits on the remote repo side.

But of course, that would not change the potential pulls/merged done before that second push, so communication would be key, in *addition* of fixing the history.